# Can't start my app using the Bluemix Live Sync "bl start" command

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, active-deploy

I want to start coding with Git and I have followed the instructions here:
https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/develop/bluemixlive.html

Using the "`bl sync`" command I created and synced my Bluemix project in my Windows local directory as shown in the screenshot below. The name of my project is "Speak Out".

"`bl sync`" command
[image: bl sync]

But when I checked the status with "`bl status`", a message was returned saying that my project had not been set up on my machine and that I needed to run the sync command.

"`bl status`" command
[image: bl status]

I have installed Bluemix Live Sync v1.0.7, Node.js v.5.8.0, and I am using Windows 10. I have tried to restart my computer to update my execution path, but nothing changed.

Can anyone help me solve my problem starting an app with Bluemix Live Sync?

Comment: Would you be able to describe your workflow (how you created your project)?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that there are spaces in your project name "Speak Out". I attempted to reproduce your problem by creating my own project with a space character in the name. I ran `bl sync` and `bl status` on both Windows 10 and Mac OS X. In both cases my `bl sync` succeeded and my `bl status` failed, although not in exactly the same way as yours. I suspect there might be a defect in the Live Sync tooling when a project name has spaces in it.

You could try working around the problem by forking your "Speak Out" project and assigning a name that has no spaces in it to the new project. Then try to sync and start the app for the new project.